# How to do user defined type that includes parameterized derived type with gfortran?

Tags: types, fortran, parameterized-types

I am learning how to use parameterized derived type in fortran. My aim is to create a user defined type that contains a parameterized derived type with length deferred. And I have a lot of problems. (Rq : compiler : `gfortran`)

First, I got an internal compilation error with this program.

```
program main

implicit none

type :: square_mat_t(mat_size) 
    integer, len :: mat_size
    real, dimension(mat_size,mat_size) :: mat
end type square_mat_t

type :: two_sqmat_t(mat_size)
    integer, len :: mat_size
    type(square_mat_t(mat_size)) :: mat1
    type(square_mat_t(mat_size)) :: mat2
end type two_sqmat_t

type(two_sqmat_t(:)), allocatable :: my_twosqmat2

end program main
```

But if `type(two_sqmat_t(2)) :: my_twosqmat1` is added before `my_twosqmat2` declaration, it compiles.

```
...
type(two_sqmat_t(2)) :: my_twosqmat1
type(two_sqmat_t(:)), allocatable :: my_twosqmat2
...
```

So I decided to try to init `my_twosqmat1` (I will see later for `my_twosqmat2`)

```
my_twosqmat1%mat1%mat(:,:) = 1
```

And I got another compilation error.

These are the error messages:

First error:

```
f951: internal compiler error: Segmentation fault
```

Second error:

```
extend_param_derived_type.f90:21:16: 21 | end program main | 1 internal compiler error: Segmentation fault –
```

So, I wonder how it is possible to write a program with an user defined type that includes a parameterized derived type using the gfortran compiler. A simple example would be welcome.

Comment: Wjat kind of error did you get exactly? Please cooy and paste the complete output.

Comment: @Vladimir. It is in French. First error : _f951: *erreur interne du compilateur: Erreur de segmentation*_ (Rough Translation : f951: ICE. Segmentation Error) and  Second error : _extend_param_derived_type.f90:21:16: end program main. Erreur interne du compilateur: Erreur de segmentation_ (ICE, Segmentation Error)

Comment: @Vladimir. gfortran version : GNU Fortran (GCC) 12.2.1 20220819

Comment: If you use linux, you can use `LANG="C"` to get English error messages https://superuser.com/questions/334800/lang-c-is-in-a-number-of-the-etc-init-d-scripts-what-does-lang-c-do-and-why

Comment: @VladimirFГероямслава. Thanks. Yes, I use Linux. These are the error messages :
First error :
f951: internal compiler error: Segmentation fault
Second error :
extend_param_derived_type.f90:21:16:

   21 | end program main
      |                1
internal compiler error: Segmentation fault

Comment: @Vladimir. Do you know how to do "CR" in comment ?

Comment: I do not know what CR is. Code is marked using the \` character both in comments and in questions/answers. Please copy the error messages into your question. Do notnuse comments for them. Be aware that an internal compiler error is a bug in the compiler. You cannot fix it by changing the code, the compiler must be fixed. You can try a more recent version, but current GCC is GCC 12, so that is what you have. You can report the error in the GCC bugzilla.

Comment: @VladimirFГероямслава. CR = Carriage return

Comment: @VladimirFГероямслава. I had contact Bugzilla. Thanks for your interest in my question